# How to avoid Central Banking System in a country?

Tags: riba, banking

I live in Indonesia where all banks is likely under a central bank. As we know that the central bank still applies interest rate, so all the 'sharia labelled' banks in Indonesia is still affected by the policy of interest rate. The banks may not giving the interest, but it charges people on other things (ex. compulsory on taking insurance).
What is the alternative to avoid this system?

Comment: Perhaps you can explain how a central bank will effect you personally? Islamic banks may index their rates with the ongoing interest rates, but that does not in itself make it riba.

Comment: @UmH I am a university student in informatics field, and I find financial industry is interesting, so I will possibly working in a bank or creating a financial service